# how to fill a view with a gradient background color

Tags: android, layout, colors

I am creating the Android version of an iPhone app, and i need them to look as close as possible.

A problem with this is creating the bars and filling them with a gradient color.

Is there a way to fill a view (probably a layout) with a gradient color, other than using background images?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a shape drawable http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape that is a gradient and set it as the background of your view.

If you want to have the gradient overlaying another image, you could use a layerlist http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer :)